# XML Suggestions Not working in android studio?

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport

i just create new project with Target & Compile SDK 33 , it disable all sugestion in xml file .
i dont know what happened .

I tried

- 1.save mode off

  2.tick the option in code completion "show suggestions as you type"

  4.invalidate cache and restart

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but this problem is solved when i Downgrade the target and compile sdk version from 33 to 32 .
its working now